# PyQt QListWidget custom items

Tags: python, pyqt, qlistwidgetitem

how can i create a QListWidgetItem that has 1 image and 2 labels/strings underneath, that have support for css?

this is the last thing i have tried:

```
class CustomListWidgetItem(QListWidgetItem, QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QListWidgetItem.__init__(self, parent)
        QLabel.__init__(self, parent)
```

i'm using PyQt btw

Comment: Can you explain why that didn't work? Did you get error messages or just not see the behavior you expected?

Comment: because in the next line i tried doing self.setText("test") and it didnt display "test"

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> how can i create a QListWidgetItem that has 1 image and 2
>   labels/strings underneath, that have support for css?

In this case, you can't (it actually has an API for adding icons easily, but two labels/strings is impossible). But, you can create your own custom widget and put it into `QtGui.QListWidget`.

1. Create your custom widget.
2. Create your `QtGui.QListWidget` in the main application.
3. Create a custom widget object and set item in `QListWidgetItem` by `QListWidgetItem` is in `QtGui.QListWidget` by using the `QListWidget.setItemWidget (self, QListWidgetItem item, QWidget widget)` method.

This is an example to explain my solution:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class QCustomQWidget (QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomQWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.textQVBoxLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.textUpQLabel    = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.textDownQLabel  = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.textQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.textUpQLabel)
        self.textQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.textDownQLabel)
        self.allQHBoxLayout  = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.iconQLabel      = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.allQHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.iconQLabel, 0)
        self.allQHBoxLayout.addLayout(self.textQVBoxLayout, 1)
        self.setLayout(self.allQHBoxLayout)
        # setStyleSheet
        self.textUpQLabel.setStyleSheet('''
            color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
        ''')
        self.textDownQLabel.setStyleSheet('''
            color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
        ''')

    def setTextUp (self, text):
        self.textUpQLabel.setText(text)

    def setTextDown (self, text):
        self.textDownQLabel.setText(text)

    def setIcon (self, imagePath):
        self.iconQLabel.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(imagePath))

class exampleQMainWindow (QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__ (self):
        super(exampleQMainWindow, self).__init__()
        # Create QListWidget
        self.myQListWidget = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
        for index, name, icon in [
            ('No.1', 'Meyoko',  'icon.png'),
            ('No.2', 'Nyaruko', 'icon.png'),
            ('No.3', 'Louise',  'icon.png')]:
            # Create QCustomQWidget
            myQCustomQWidget = QCustomQWidget()
            myQCustomQWidget.setTextUp(index)
            myQCustomQWidget.setTextDown(name)
            myQCustomQWidget.setIcon(icon)
            # Create QListWidgetItem
            myQListWidgetItem = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(self.myQListWidget)
            # Set size hint
            myQListWidgetItem.setSizeHint(myQCustomQWidget.sizeHint())
            # Add QListWidgetItem into QListWidget
            self.myQListWidget.addItem(myQListWidgetItem)
            self.myQListWidget.setItemWidget(myQListWidgetItem, myQCustomQWidget)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.myQListWidget)

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
window = exampleQMainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Note:** I have image file `icon.png`, size 48 x 48 pixel.

[QListWidget.setItemWidget](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlistwidget.html#setItemWidget)

**Experimental result**

[image]

Comment: This example is too fabulous awesome! (With Nyaruko wwww) Thank you!

Comment: Bump. 
I have a question here @Kitsune
How would you access the items in myQCustomQWidget ?
If i select the [0] row from the main QList how would i access to the text variable in myQCustomQWidget for example the TextDown ?

Comment: @Arukaito, you could simply add a method in class QCustomQWidget

`def getTextUp(self):
      return self.textUpQLabel.text()`

and access it as follows
`for row in range(self.myQListWidget.count()):
     item = self.myQListWidget.itemWidget(self.list.item(row))
     text = item.getTextUp()`