# PyQt: how to create a multiline list widget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Basically, I have text in a table that I would like to be displayed as a list in my GUI application.

What I have:

```
column1    | column2    | column3   |

-----------| -----------| ----------|

col1atext  | col2atext  | col3atext |

col1btext  | col2btext  | col3btext |
```

What I need:

```
col1atext    #wrap to the next line  

col2atext    #wrap to the next line

col3atext      

------------

col1btext    #wrap to the next line

col2btext    #wrap to the next line

col3btext      

------------
```

I have exhausted my Google search, and have not found any examples of this. Everything I see allows for just one line of text in a list, but I'd like to show a list of lists (multiple lines of text). I could just create a single string of text with enough spaces between the separate pieces of text in order to force text wrapping over several lines, but that doesn't seem like a real solution (pseudocode below).

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
import PCA_mod2ui #UI design file

class PCAmod2App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, PCA_mod2ui.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PCAmod2App, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        ## below defined in PCA_mod2ui, converted from QT Designer
        """
        self.projectListWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.projectListWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 311, 531))
        self.projectListWidget.setLineWidth(1)
                self.projectListWidget.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.projectListWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
            self.projectListWidget.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
            self.projectListWidget.setHorizontalScrollMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerItem)
        self.projectListWidget.setProperty("isWrapping", True)
        self.projectListWidget.setWordWrap(True)
        self.projectListWidget.setSelectionRectVisible(True)
        self.projectListWidget.setObjectName("projectListWidget")
        """
        dpspace = ' '
        spacer =95

        datapoint1a='text1'
        datapoint1b='text2'
        datapoint1c='text3'
        d1aspace = dpspace*(spacer-len(datapoint1a))
        d1bspace = dpspace*(spacer-len(datapoint1b))
        datapoint1 =datapoint1a+d1aspace+datapoint1b+d1bspace+datapoint1c

        datapoint2a='2'+datapoint1a
        datapoint2b='2'+datapoint1b
        datapoint2c='2'+datapoint1c
        d2aspace = dpspace*(spacer-len(datapoint2a))
        d2bspace = dpspace*(spacer-len(datapoint2b))
        datapoint2 =datapoint2a+d2aspace+datapoint2b+d2bspace+datapoint2c

        datalist=[datapoint1,datapoint2]

        self.projectListWidget.addItems(datalist)

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = PCAmod2App()
    form.show() #show the form
    app.exec_() #execute the app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any ideas to make this better?

Update 4/10/17: found a solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187444/pyqt-qlistwidget-custom-items).

Comment: You could explain better.

Comment: I am a beginner, so excuse me if I don't know the perfect words for this. If you think of an Excel spreadsheet where you have 3 columns for 3 attributes of data per row, the transformation I'm looking for is combining 3 cells into 1 cell, with each attribute on a new line.

Comment: So you mean you have an Excel spreadsheet? Or which kind of table do you have?

Comment: Do you want a list where each item is another list?

Comment: No, the data is coming from a SQL database. I would like it displayed in a single column, selectable list.

Comment: Do you want a list where each item is another list?

Comment: Yes, each item in the main list would technically be another list.

Comment: And you want every element in the main list to have a title, that's what the asterisks mean?

Comment: I see you deleted the asterisks.

Comment: They were bolded. Your edit made the bold formatting go away, and the asterisks were left behind.

Comment: You want the text to be aligned to the right?