# Python PyQt4 QFileDialog images and load in QListWidget

Tags: python, pyqt4, qlistwidget, qfiledialog

I'm new in python and cannot find similar case to my ideal output. Is this possible to python? Select images to file and load in QListWidget with image thumbnails and file name. This idea is like a Matlab ImageLabeler (pls see image fyr)

Sample Image

[image]

Below so far is my code applied by the QListWidget doeesn't appear. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
    def open_file(self):

    listWidget = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
    listWidget.move(0, 80)
    name = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, 'Open File', "", "Image Files (*.jpg *.png *bmp *gif);; "
                                                                     "All Files(*.*)")
    filelist = list(name)
    for image in filelist:
        listWidget.addItem(image)
```

Comment: https://www.pythoncentral.io/pyside-pyqt-tutorial-the-qlistwidget/

Comment: look for `ImageFileList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's already achieved here [Custom QlistWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187444/pyqt-qlistwidget-custom-items). You need to create a custom list widget that base on your target output like icon and label then add widget. Upon calling to your custom widget you will set what data appears on your assigned or added widget to your listwidget.

Comment: Thanks I applied that custom widget and works perfectly.